# What happens when Adamantine strikes Adamantine?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, armor, special-materials

I'm going to cut to the chase, in D&D 5e, if a player wearing adamantine armor gets hit with an adamantine weapon, what happens?

Comment: Related: [What difference does it make for a weapon to be made of adamantine?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108804)

Answer (score 7):

### The player is not an object; the hit is a normal hit

[Adamantine Armor is a magic item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/adamantine-armor) from the DMG. The relevant effect:

> While you're wearing it, any critical hit against you becomes a normal hit.

Adamantine weapons on the other hand are described in [*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#AdamantineWeapons) (emphasis added):

> Whenever an adamantine weapon or piece of ammunition *hits an object*, the hit is a critical hit.

[Since creatures are not objects](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114722/52137), adamantine weapons have no extra effect and it's a non-critical hit (even if the d20 roll was a 20).

For using adamantine weapons against adamantine objects (assuming they inherit the property of the armor) there are two contradicting specific exceptions to the general rules, so the DM is expected to use their sound judgement (this also applies to dealing with objects in general). Personally I would lean towards the effects canceling each-other, and would consider applying that as a house-rule to the original scenario, should it ever come up (at least if it's one of my PCs wielding the weapon).

Comment: Related, maybe worth citing: [Is there anything that is simultaneously a creature and an object?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/116035)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Cheers. I thought about rooting out that q and linking it, but that saves me from digging. :)

Comment: Your last paragraph says there’s a contradiction when there isn’t. If I use an adamantine weapon to hit unworn adamantine armor it’s a critical hit because the armor only avoids critical son the person wearing it.

Comment: @DaleM That's why I state the assumption about the object inheriting the armor property (ie negating critical hits). Objects, and the damage to them isn't exactly given too much attention in the rules.